# How to update a thing certificate in AWS IoT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

How do I update the certificate of an existing Thing in AWS IoT, assuming I know the thing name and an attribute with the same value? I.e. the thing has name `"foo"` and attribute `"id=foo"`.

From the limited documentation, I'm assuming I do something like:

- Register the replacement certificate ([`RegisterCertificate`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_RegisterCertificate.html))
- Find the existing thing ([`ListThings`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_ListThings.html), filtered by attribute)
- Attach the new certificate to the Thing ([`AttachThingPrincipal`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_AttachThingPrincipal.html)?)
- Somehow find the old certificate (is there no better way than [`ListCertificates`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_ListCertificates.html) and paging)??
- Update the old certificate to be INACTIVE ([`UpdateCertificate`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_UpdateCertificate.html))

Can anyone confirm the correct, most succinct way to do this?

Comment: During my testing, I've discovered I can simply register the Thing for a second time. That gets me 90% of the way there - I end up with a Thing with two certificates, both with the correct policy. So the final act is to remove the old cert. This feels a bit grim though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I welcome better solutions, but this worked for me:

1. Call `RegisterThing` again (same ThingName, same policy, different cert). This seems to attach a new certificate to my thing.
2. Called `ListThingPrincipals`, filtering on ThingName. The result will be a list of ARNs representing the certificates associated with the thing, of the form `arn:aws:iot:<region>:<account id>:cert/<cert id>`.
3. Iterative through the list, strip out the certificate id and call `DescribeCertificate`, with the certificate id as parameter.
4. Compare the result (which includes the PEM form of the certificate) with the new certificate. If it's not a match, this is one of the previous certificates. Consequently, call `UpdateCertificate` and mark that certificate as `INACTIVE`.